# How to reuse PreparedStatement that depends on the result of the execution

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

My objective is this:

I have a `SELECT` query with that I want to run on a database with a lot of rows. This query will produce a LOT of results, so I was thinking of running it in iterations with `LIMIT 1000` and `OFFSET ?` where `?` will be the last row that were processed in each iteration.

Eg:

- Get rows 1 - 1000
- Get rows 1001 - 2000
- Get rows 2001 - 3000
- Get rows 3001 - 4000
- ...

I was thinking about doing it in a loop where the each new iteration will set the last iteration's row as the new iteration's `OFFSET` (Eg: `OFFSET 1001`, `OFFSET 2001`, etc. as shown above).

I am new to using JDBC, so **is this the correct way to do it**? If so, how do I re-use `PreparedStatement` when I must execute it and get the result for each iteration?

If this isn't the correct way to do it, what is the correct way?

**EDIT**:
Here's my current code:

```
private static void import(Date from, Date to) throws Exception {

    PreparedStatement p = connect.prepareStatement(statement);
    p.setInt(1, 0);
    p.add
    ResultSet results;
    for (int i=0; i< WAVES; i++) {
        results = p.executeQuery();
        Integer lastRow = importFrom(results);
        p.setInt(1, lastRow.intValue()+1);
        results.close();
    }
    p.close();
}
```

**EDIT 2**:
Here's the SQL String:

```
SELECT 
item.aitem_id, item.action_type, item.user_id, item.pid, item.pr_id, item.action_time, item.notes, item.screen, item.vid, item.lo_id,
vals.value_name, vals.simple_int_value, vals.simple_double_value, vals.simple_date_value, vals.simple_string_value,
data.version_id, data.prev_version_id
FROM mySchema.aitems item
JOIN mySchema.avalues vals ON item.aitem_id=vals.aitem_id
JOIN mySchema.adata data ON item.aitem_id=data.aitem_id
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET ?;
```

I modified both my code and SQL to prepare with only the `OFFSET`.

Comment: Could you please give the full select statement?

Comment: Why split it?  This is likely more inefficient than retrieving all your data at once.  Especially if you're breaking them up into small chunks of 1000.

Comment: I wanted to split it because it is a DB with live production data so I  didn't want to affect performance. And my query without limits would generate about 1.6 million results.

Comment: You would be making 1600 database calls - very inefficient.  Perhaps a re-evaluation of what you're trying to accomplish is in order.  Sounds like an ETL job.

Comment: Yes, that does sound inefficient. I'm new to working directly with JDBC, so can you suggest how I should go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

What your doing is correct but It would be a good idea to add a call to `clearParameters()` and uses `try finally` blocks. Below is how I would implement it

```
PreparedStatement p = null;
ResultSet results = null;
Integer lastRow = 0;
try
{
    p = connect.prepareStatement(statement);
    p.add

    for (int i=0; i< WAVES; i++) 
    {
        p.clearParameters();
        p.setInt(1,lastRow.intValue() + 1)
        try  // This try might not really be necessary
        {
            results = p.executeQuery();
            Integer lastRow = importFrom(results);
            p.setInt(1, lastRow.intValue()+1);
        } // Add dealing with exceptions
        finally
        {
            results.close();
        }
    }
} //Add dealing with exceptions
finally
{
    p.close();
}
```

Comment: sorry, that is a typo that occured as a modified my code after pasting it here. I fixed that, but it didn't fix the issue. That generated a runtime error and I fixed it.

Comment: Thought it probably would have been a typo. So what is the issue you are getting?

Comment: The amount of results I end up getting is much less than the amount of rows I get if I execute the query in a DBMS program.

Comment: Well this is then most likely related to your method `importFrom` or the variable `WAVES`

Comment: I suspect it's `importFrom()`, so I am doing some debugging right now. I'll report back with results. Here's my WAVES: `private static final int WAVES = 200;`

Comment: yep. Figured it out. problem was in `importFrom()`. The integer it returned was wrong. I was using a joined query that had a one-to-many relationship, so there were additional rows that weren't properly being accounted for. Thank you for your help. I also took your advice and implemented try/catch/finally blocks instead of throwing and missing the `close()` statements.